# PHP - Undefined Index after posting form

Tags: php, forms, post, indexing, undefined

I have write the following form code :

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="cible.php">

<p>Prénom</p> <!-- ZONE DE TEXTE -->
<input type="text" name="prenom" />
<input type="submit" value="Valider" />
<br />

<p>Message</p> <!-- ZONE DE TEXTE MULTILIGNES -->
<textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="45">Votre message ici.</textarea>
<br />

<p>Pays</p> <!-- LISTE DEROULANTE -->
<select name="pays">
  <option value="Suisse" selected="selected">Suisse</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="Allemagne">Allemagne</option>
  <option value="Angleterre">Angleterre</option>
  <option value="Italie">Italie</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Plateforme</p> <!-- CASE A COCHER -->
<input type="checkbox" name="case" value="acer" id="case" /> <label for="case">Acer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="case" value="asus" id="case" /> <label for="case">Asus</label>
<br />

<p>Sexe</p> <!-- BOUTON RADIO -->
<input type="radio" name="sexe" value="Homme" id="m" checked="checked" /> <label for="Homme">Masculin</label>
<input type="radio" name="sexe" value="Femme" id="f" /> <label for="Femme">Féminin</label>

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

echo $_POST["prenom"] . "<br />";
echo $_POST["message"] . "<br />";
echo $_POST["pays"] . "<br />";

if ($_POST["case"] == "acer")
{
    echo $_POST["case"] . "<br />";
}
else if ($_POST["case"] == "asus")
{
    echo $_POST["case"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
    echo "Pas de plateforme";
}

echo $_POST["sexe"] . "<br />";

?>
```

The PHP code means :

> If visitor chooses "acer", write his choice. If visitor chooses
>   "asus", write his choice. Else, write : "Pas de plateforme".

But when I "post" the form, it tells me :

> undefined index : case in ...

Can someone help me fixing this ?

Thank you.
Chris.

Comment: It would be nice if you tell use the line (not the number, e.g. the beginning of the line) where php detects an error

Comment: Line 7 and 11 (in PHP code).

Comment: Is this your complete PHP code?

Comment: Line 7 and 11 (in PHP code).

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$_POST` and look if `case` is defined.

Comment: **SOLVED :**

    <?php
    
    echo $_POST["prenom"] . "<br />";
    echo $_POST["message"] . "<br />";
    echo $_POST["pays"] . "<br />";
    if (isset($_POST["case"]))
    {
        echo $_POST["case"] . "<br />";
    }
    echo $_POST["sexe"] . "<br />";
    
    ?>

Comment: what if you check both the checkboxes??Pass checkbox name as an array and in the php use for loop to retrieve those multiple values..

Answer (score 0):

Using checkboxes means "case" would return an array so you would need to see if case['asus']  was set and value equaled 1.

Comment: Then php would throw another exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in action file:

```
<?php

echo $_POST["prenom"] . "<br />";
echo $_POST["message"] . "<br />";
echo $_POST["pays"] . "<br />";

if (!empty($_POST["case"])) {
    if ($_POST["case"] == "acer") {
        echo $_POST["case"] . "<br />";
    } else if ($_POST["case"] == "asus") {
        echo $_POST["case"] . "<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "Pas de plateforme" . "<br />";
}

echo $_POST["sexe"] . "<br />";
?>
```